# Unexpected token error with this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've noticed that when I use this block of code, I get an error somewhere in my code that there is an unexpected token either in a equal sign (=) in an assignment or a full-stop (.) in a function call.

Can someone help me fix this code so that it works with the rest of my code, which is working fine and error-free?

```
 else{
     var x = $('#main .dataCard').sort(function (a, b) {
          return $(a).data('cardnumber') - $(b).data('cardnumber');
     });

     for(var i = 0; i < x.length;i++){
        if($('#left').height() <= $('#right').height()){
            $('#left').append(x[i]);
        }
        else
            ('#right').append(x[i]);  
    });
    console.log("#1");
 }
```

Comment: More code, more details would be helpful if you want an answer. I see nothing obvious wrong.

Comment: First of all, show a complete example, or do you really have an `else` without `if`? Secondly, which line exactly is it that the error message points to?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is about a basic syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A handy tool is jslint or jshint to catch small bugs. I've tweaked your code above to add a missing `$`, and remove a `)` so that it goes through without any errors. You can ignore the top if statement I used to make the statement whole for others to see.

```
'use strict';

if(10 % 2 === 0) {
    return 2;
} else {

    var x = $('#main .dataCard').sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).data('cardnumber') - $(b).data('cardnumber');
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < x.length;i++){
       if($('#left').height() <= $('#right').height()){
           $('#left').append(x[i]);
       } else {
              $('#right').append(x[i]);
       }
    }

   console.log("#1");
}
```

I highly encourage you to play with installing different linters. They make it super easy to spot small errors in your code.

You can find JSHint [here](https://github.com/jshint/jshint)
You can find JSLint [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint)

You can use them either within your text editor, or as command line tools.